# Bitcoin-qt is trying toload to C drive instead of my D drive

Tags: blockchain, wallet, installation

So I'm running a 250 GB SSHD for my windows boot drive and basic system functions. I am running a 1 TB standard HD for my larger files (like the bitcoin ledger). How do I prevent Bitcoin-qt from loading the ledger to my C drive and instead have it load to my D drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `bitcoin.conf` file that specifies `datadir=(your/desired/filepath)` in order to override the default data directory location.